Are $\mathcal S$ and $s$ isomorphic as Frechet algebras?
$\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ (the space of Schwarz functions) and $s$ (the space of rapidly decreasing sequences) are isomorphic as Fréchet spaces: it suffices to use the absolute basis composed of Hermite functions in $\mathcal S$ to obtain the isomorphism (i.e. $f\mapsto (f,H_n)$).
However, that bijection does not behave nicely wrt the algebraic structure of the two spaces, hence my question: are the two spaces isomorphic as algebras?
